# Mysql stored procedure limit on query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i just want limit a query by parameter inside a stored, but I get an error in the LIMIT field:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test//
CREATE PROCEDURE test(lim INT)
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM logs LIMIT 0,lim; 
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

What I miss?

Comment: it works for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: I get: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lim;
  END' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL LIMIT clause has some limitations. Refer to a known [***`bug id=11918` here***](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918).

> *This isn't specific to stored routines.*
>   *LIMIT doesn't allow variables in any context*.
>   *Its arguments must be integer constants.*

A workaround is using prepared statements in stored procedures.

**Example**:

```
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS names_proc;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE names_proc( lim INT )
    ->   BEGIN
    ->     PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM names LIMIT 0, ?';
    ->     EXECUTE STMT USING @lim;
    ->   END;
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> CALL names_proc( 3 );
+------+----------+
| id   | name     |
+------+----------+
|    1 | jimjoe   |
|    2 | jimddjoe |
|    3 | jim      |
+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```